# D3js: How to interpolate datasets with irregular time intervals before stacking them?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

UPDATE: The jsfiddle example illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/T8SuH/

I am new to both D3js and JavaScript but comfortable with Java. I have a large CSV dataset from a bike-sharing system organized as follows:

```
event_id, station_id, timestamp, number_of_bikes, number_of_empty_docks
```

To reduce file size, my data file contains only new events for individual stations. Therefore timestamps of different stations are neither in regular time intervals nor they coincide. For example consecutive entries might look like this:

```
31044955, 08, 2012-05-01 00:00:00, 9, 6
31044965, 23, 2012-05-01 00:32:00, 2, 6
31044972, 02, 2012-05-01 00:44:00, 10, 5
31044999, 17, 2012-05-01 02:10:10, 12, 6
...
```

I want to create a stacked area chart in which the x axis is time (24hrs) and the y axis is (stacked) inventories from selected stations. D3 Wiki mentions that data should be interpolated before computing the stack. I consider two ways of doing this:
- Interpolate my dataset outside D3 (using Java) and save it as a new CSV file in which all stations have concurrent timestamps. This method would increase my file size more than 6 times (currently it is 25MB) and I fear that D3 would be then slow in processing it. 
- Interpolate data inside D3/Javascript before doing the stack or plotting the area/path.

While I feel the second way would be faster (in terms of performance), I do not know how to do this and I haven't found any related tutorials/examples. I only guess that I would have to create a range (d3.time.minute.range) and then use it with a map() function to create a new array? Could someone please provide a suggestion of how to interpolate multiple datasets (e.g. for each station) with irregular time intervals before stacking them, inside D3?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to interpolate values. Can you not simply use a [time scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales) for your x-axis?

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure what you mean by interpolate. But if you think about what a stacked bar polygon will look like you will certainly need data points for all stations for all timestamps (even if station A has no event at time X it will have a vertex because it is pushed by the area for station B). So you need to iterate through all times and fill in values for stations with no events. You can certainly do this with javascript.

Comment: The following jsfiddle illustrates the problem: jsfiddle.net/T8SuH In the jsfiffle example I have modified slightly the timestamps of each of the three groups. My question is if there is a straightforward way to re-interpolate the data in JS or D3. If I do that externally, I will end up with a significantly larger datafile. Any link to an example/tutorial or guideline would be much helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem once before. With a little bit of delicacy you can add in the missing values so that every series has the same set of x-coordinates (timestamps). I added a few lines to you jsfiddle to massage the data before you send it into the stack layout.

To start with I needed the super-set of times:

```
var times = [];
myData.forEach(function(d) {
  if(times.indexOf(d.date.getTime()) === -1) {
    times.push(d.date.getTime());
  }
});
times.sort();
```

This results in the array (from your data):

```
0:00, 4:00, 4:30, 4:45, 8:08, 12:08, 13:08, 16:08, 20:08
```

Note that at the end I sort it because this will really simplify finding the missing values in the station data series. I intend to do a kind of sorted list merge to fill in no-change data values into the series. This is what your series look like straight from the data (time value pairs):

```
Initial series
Station_1 0:00 37, 4:30 36, 8:08 18, 12:08 10, 16:08 32, 20:08 35
Station_2 0:00 32, 4:00 29, 8:08 6,  12:08 12, 16:08 29, 20:08 32
Station_3 0:00 36, 4:45 30, 8:08 10, 13:08 13, 16:08 32, 20:08 36
Station_4 0:00 31, 4:00 28, 8:08 12, 12:08 14, 16:08 28, 20:08 31
```

So for each series, walk through the time array and insert missing values, there may well be a more efficient way to do this:

```
myNestedData.forEach(function(stationData) {
  stationData.values.sort(function(a,b) {
      return d3.ascending(a.date.getTime(), b.date.getTime());
    });
  var j = 0;
  var lastStationValue = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    // If the station series is too short I should not equal any 
    // value from the times array
    stationTime = j <= stationData.values.length ?
        stationData.values[j].date.getTime() : 0;

    if(times[i] !== stationTime) {
      // Missing values need to be spliced in.
      stationData.values.splice(j, 0, { 
          date: new Date(times[i]),
          inventory: lastStationValue,
          station_id: stationData.key
      });
      j++;
    }
    else {
      // We have a value for this time, move along.
      lastStationValue = stationData.values[j].inventory;
      j++;
    }
  }                       
});
```

And now the series should all line up!

```
Station_1 0:00 37, 4:00 37, 4:30 36, 4:45 36, 8:08 18, 12:08 10, 13:08 10, 16:08 32, 20:08 35
Station_2 0:00 32, 4:00 29, 4:30 29, 4:45 29, 8:08 6,  12:08 12, 13:08 12, 16:08 29, 20:08 32
Station_3 0:00 36, 4:00 36, 4:30 36, 4:45 30, 8:08 10, 12:08 10, 13:08 13, 16:08 32, 20:08 36
Station_4 0:00 31, 4:00 28, 4:30 28, 4:45 28, 8:08 12, 12:08 14, 13:08 14, 16:08 28, 20:08 31
```

You can check out the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/5wwN3/)

Comment: Oh, also I modified you svg area interpolation mode (from "cardinal" to "basis") to make the curves smooth again.

Comment: Thanks Superboggly - that s exactly what I wanted to do. Very helpful and concise!

Comment: I wonder if the Array sorting method get overly slow as my data file gets bigger. In the compressed version I have around 500,000 lines of data (about 25MB). If it gets too slow, I may have to do this process externally, save it as a larger data file, and use D3 only to visualize it?

Comment: You may have better performance filling in your timelines externally. Are you visualizing the whole dataset at once? Can you round the timestamps to 5min intervals?

Comment: @Dimitris, I've been dealing with similar issues of how to display a massive amount of data.  I aggregate it into "bins" and then, when the user zooms in, I re-aggregate it.  The main question is how interactive should it be?  If you're only concerned about loading the data once, then use a spinner (or something).  Otherwise, maybe cut the data up: you could take contiguous chunks or even every X datapoints - there shouldn't be much difference in squeezing 200,000 lines of data in 800 pixels of width or 500,000.. think about normalizing the data.

Comment: @Superboggly: Yes, I need to visualize the entire dataset at once. I want to be able to average data for either individual or groups of stations over days, weeks, or months, or simply zoom into any particular day of my entire timeline. Indeed, I ended up rounding the timestamps of my dataset over 5min (~60MB) or 15min (~20MB) intervals.

Comment: @arigold, as I explain in the previous comment I want to be able to not only zoom in time, but also to dynamically average data of individual or grouped stations over selected time periods, interactively. I guess binning data externally & using a spinner is the way to go...