# d3 time data with irregular intervals

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to plot values by date, grouped by location.  The difficulty is that my samples are taken at different locations on different dates.  The dates are irregular at each location.

The resulting graph should look something like: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

My question is similar to [D3js: How to interpolate datasets with irregular time intervals before stacking them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806789/d3js-how-to-interpolate-datasets-with-irregular-time-intervals-before-stacking), however the answer there is to insert data points where they are missing.  That doesn't work for my case, I want points on the graph to indicate points where actual data exists, and have d3 put a smooth line connecting the points.

I'm brand new to d3.  I could really use an example of how to do this, if it is possible.

Comment: It would help if you could post your code and data.

Comment: If you just want a line graph, not a stacked area graph, you don't need to do anything special.  Each line has its own data set with its own x and y points.  The stacked area graph was a special case, because you need to know the total of the all the series lower down in the stack at each point in time.